# How to use sheet Code Name in loop with sheet Name , VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this line of code to loop between specific sheets
`For Each WS In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2","Sheet3"))`

**Problem:** instead of "Sheet3" , I need to use it's code name **Sheet03**
I tried
`For Each WS In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2",Sheet03))` but I got error Type mismatch

[image]

Comment: Untested - Try `For Each WS In Array(Sheets("Sheet1"),Sheets("Sheet2"),Sheet03)`, `WS` might need to be declared as `Variant`

Comment: I am really sorry , I did not see WS might need to be declared as `Variant` , I tried again and it works perfectly @Raymond Wu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
For Each WS In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", Sheet03.Name))
```